# Quartz.Net Scheduler - Cron Trigger Configuration

Tags: triggers, cron, quartz.net, schedule

I need to create a cron trigger that fires at 09:00am, 11:00am, 13:00pm, 15:00pm and 17:00pm, only week days, in Brazil timezone. Can anyone help me please??
I already tried several ways and could not make it work.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UTC time:

```
0 0 9-17/2 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

if Brazil timezone is -3 UTC, then this should be

```
0 0 12-20/2 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

You can use [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) utility to generate/check cron expression.